# Removed GNOME log software

Tags: gnome, software-installation, 20.04, log

I accidentally deleted the GNOME logs package using Synaptic in Ubuntu 20.04. Can it have negative impacts on my system? If so can I get it back?

Comment: the thing is i have read that the pre-installed packages are integrated with the system and removing them isn't good. So is there no negative effects on my system?

Comment: If something goes wrong, you can install the package you've deleted back at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine one of those cool stone walls without any mortar.

[image: Inca wall of dry stone construction in Cusco, Peru, courtesy of Wikimedia]

That's Ubuntu. It's made up of packages (stones) without any additional magic (mortar).

If you pull a package out, you can put it back in using the same tools.

- You used Synaptic to remove a package, you can use Synaptic to put it back.

Many user-facing packages on top *depend upon* foundational packages at the bottom. You can remove those top user-facing packages without any harm. However, it's very unwise to pull out one of those foundational packages, since it will require the removal of lots of packages above it.

- A log-reading application is one of those user-facing (top) applications. Nothing else *depends* upon it. If there had been dependencies, Synaptic would have warned you.

Ubuntu is merely a set of pre-curated packages that are tested to fit together. There's no magic. It's all open-source. Nothing is hidden. You can see how it's made and how the packages fit together (if you have the skills to understand -- it's a bit technical).

Comment: all right thanks for that detailed answer, it helped a lot :)